# Symfony2 Form for nested array

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

How to create form for nested array in Symfony2?

I have an array:

```
$array = [
   'data' => 'some',
   'nested' => [ 
       'data' => 'more' 
   ] 
];
```

How to create form for editing this array?

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($array)
// ???
->getForm();
```

I need form only for editing fields 'some' and 'more'.

**UPDATE**
I found only this way:

```
$arrayFacade = new DotNotation($array);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($arrayFacade)
        ->add('data')
        ->add('nested:more')
        ->getForm();
```

DotNotation: https://gist.github.com/elfet/4713488

Comment: Is this were you looking for? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Yes. How to do this without create classes?

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
     ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'data' => $array['name'],
        'label' => 'Your name'
     )
    ->getForm();
$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('mySecondForm', 'collection', array(
        'type' => $form
    )
    ->getForm();
```

Why you don't want to create classes and use entities?

Comment: And how to push array here?

Comment: Try to call $form->getData() - structure of array is incorrect.